Is it impossible to get refresh token in c#?
My goal is managing user's access token by refresh token. Because, I don't want to require login(interactive) after once login.
And, I need to personal user token. So, I use "AcquireTokenInteractive"
I hope to get refresh token when I get access token. But, I can't get it.
It's my code.
I want to request token by c#
// var scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Mail.Read", "offline_access" }; // I tried
var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default  offline_access" };

try
{


var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();

var authResult = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync().Result;

var accounts = app.GetAccountsAsync("refresh_token").Result;

token = authResult.AccessToken;
var token2 = authResult.AuthenticationResultMetadata.TokenEndpoint;

And also, In my Azure app added api/permissions "User.Read, offline_access, Mail.Read" .
Some document said, In .Net environment can't get refresh token by security reasons. So, if I want to use refresh token. Do I need to use cache?
It's refer to this ask's answer that

How to get refresh token in MSAL .Net C#
Azure AD login using C#. Acquiring Refresh token and Access token

In sum, I guess the reason from my code and azure setting issue? Or Basically, I can't get refresh token in my situation(like environment, security reason and so on)?

"But, I can't get it." What do you mean? Do you get an error? If so, which message?

Refresh token is available for auth code flow, in your screnario, you are setting the scope as /.default which is for client credential flow, no refresh token is available in this flow. As a side note, refresh tokens will never be granted with this flow as client_id and client_secret (which would be required to obtain a refresh token) can be used to obtain an access token instead.

You are authenticated without signed-in user and in that case refresh token is not available.

@Pac0 I mean I cant't get refresh token. I'm not get an error

@user2250152 I thought that by using AcquireTokenInteractive, which requires user login to obtain token values, it necessitates user authentication.

@TinyWang I actually thought I wasn't using 'client_id' and 'client_secret'. The clientId in 'PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)' within the body of my question refers to the id (appId) of my Azure app that I created. If this confusion stems from terminology, then it's my mistake. Am I correct in understanding this, or have I misunderstood something?

Is there a way to require minimal user login while still allowing backend management of the user's personal token?

My bad, sorry. https://graph.microsoft.com/.default is the scope only for client credential flow, and client credential flow must use client id + client secret/credential certificate. the words granted with this flow as client_id and client_secret are from the client crendential flow document, just want to prove it's impossible to get refresh token here.

Is different way that "var scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Mail.Read", "offline_access" };" ?

May I know what kind of application you are composing now? asp.net core mvc? blazor server /wsam? or some other types?

I use asp.net core mvc

asp.net core mvc integrating Azure AD doesn't reuqire to use the PublicClientApplicationBuilder, just follow the offical sample to add the module. Or we can create a new .net core mvc application using vs 2022 template and choose the authentication type as Microsoft identity platform. In this scenario, we don't require to manage the access token, just use the Graph SDK, it would help us call graph api. The same for refresh token, we don't need refresh token too.

I had a test before using MSAL v4.x it has a little differences between the latest version 5.x

Any other update on this question? To be honest, I never used  AAD Refresh token in my project, I prefer to generate a new token.

I tried to manage the user access token by refresh token. Because my search function needs a personal access token. But, it's not a good way and I can't get it. So, I find another way. Its search range is limited by user access sites with upn.
get user ID(users/{userUPN}) -> get belong group(users/{userId}/memberOf) -> get site(groups/{groupId}/sites/{site-id})

Thanks for your help. I decided to go with a different approach, but I really appreciate all the insights and assistance

In .net core MVC application, we can directly integrate Azure AD and Graph SDK to allow users to sign in with their microsoft account and call MS graph API onbehalf of the user. And it's simple to use the VS 2022 template.

Then change the applicationsettings.json
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "Domain": "tenantId",
  "TenantId": "tenantId",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},

And manage the nuget packages.
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.15.2" />
</ItemGroup>

Change Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

We can inject Graph client into authorized controller and call graph SDK, without access token.
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;

[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient,ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
        var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "File.Read.All", "Sites.Read.All" });
        return View();
    }
}

If we want to generate an access token used to call other APIs, we can inject ITokenAcquistion. The ITokenAcquistion I wrote in codes above is used to generate access token, when the user sign-in status hasn't expire, it can generate new access token directly, so that we don't require refresh token.
If you don't want to call graph API on behalf of the user, but want to on behalf the application, then client credential flow is required. Just using codes below.
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_id";
var clientId = "client_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

